# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When the header is click, I want it navigate to next page. However, I do not know how to access navigation props outside the class. Any suggestion on how to do this?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList} from 'react-native'

class header extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => **this.props.navigation.navigate('PageTwo')**}
        >
          <Text>{'Go to next Page Two'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export default class PageOne extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Page One',
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: // ...
    };
  }

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    // ...
  );

  render(){
    return(
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={header}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Navigation I assume?

use the `withNavigation` HOC (https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/aead8ff9fbd2aceb2d06c8049c8ad0d55d77b5ab/docs/api/withNavigation.md)

Answer (score 2):

For React Navigation 
First make sure you installed react-navigation lib in your project.
If not then run "npm install --save react-navigation" in cmd.
Then create an App.js file to hold all router names like

**App.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import Splash from './src/components/Splash/Splash'
import Login from './src/components/Splash/Login'

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  Splash : {
    screen : Splash
  },
  Login : {
    screen : Login
  },
})
export default Navigation;
```

In my case src is dirtecory for store all js file.

Now set AppRegistry.registerComponent in index.android.js.

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Splash from './src/components/Splash/Splash'
import Navigation from './App'
export class FirstReactDemo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Splash/>
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstReactDemo', () => Navigation);
```

Now, set onclick listener in first screen.

**Splash.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class SplashScreen extends Component {



static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Splash',
    };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text
          onPress={() =>navigate('Login')}
          style={styles.text}>My Splash screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Create Login.js file for next screen.

Answer (score 0):

pass `navigation = {navigation}` yourself while using your child component.

Comment: Sorry for bumping, but how do I do it? Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640941/react-native-reset-route-back-to-home-page